# FedEx Print Ground Shipping label w/ Tracking Number

Tags: vb.net, web-services, label, fedex

I have no problem printing an Express shipping label.
The ground shipping label doesn't want to put the tracking number in the label.  Has anyone had a similar problem?

I return a tracking number like this.

`GROUND
        800027415019375`

When it goes to print the label with all the data it doesn't put in the tracking number, instead it puts in this.

`A690,418,0,5,2,2,N,"G"
B80,933,0,1E,4,2,290,N,"9612019000000000000000"
A135,1247,0,4,1,1,N,"(9612019) 0000000 00000000"`

Anyone have an idea how to change this using some fedex webservice call.  It does it automatically for express, just not for ground.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was on test account federal express prints its own fake numbers that don't represent what a valid production # looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible you don't have a ground acct number connected to your express acct number. This is the behavior that results from that.